# How to generate C# properties for database column values?

Tags: c#, database

I am having a column in database where i have multiple entries for it. I need to generate c# properties for those column values. Is there any best way to do it?

Comment: what do you mean by "multiple entries for it"?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple if you know how to map C# data types with Database data types. String vs (char,varchar,nvarchar...etc) and int vs (tinyint, smallInt..etc) ...etc

But if you need a tool, you may be looking for Entity Data Model Tool or edmx. Follow the steps in this MSDN article. it is pretty simple https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716703(v=vs.100).aspx